# Fields with `updatable=false` cannot be changed with `@PrePersist` callback

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

I have several fields in my entities which are supposed to never change after they have been inserted into the database.

**Problem:**
If want to set those fields via `@PrePersist` callback method, those fields will not be persisted. This is caused by the fact, that EclipseLink is creating an INSERT statement in the first place, and creates an UPDATE statement afterwards to set the field, which have been changed in the callback method.
In the UPDATE statement the fields marked with `updatable=false` are skipped, so they will never be persisted in the database.

> Any suggestions how to resolve this?

A very basic example for this would be some audit logging, where I want to save the date of creation of my entity, e.g.

**Additional Question:**
Is this expected behaviour according to the JPA spec or is it EclipseLink specific? Is e.g. Hibernate dealing with this the same way?

I am using JPA 2.1 (EclipseLink 2.6.0)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but is this a situation where you should be using polymorphism instead of overriding column values with @PerPersist callback? If not please provide some examples of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jimeh There is a simple example given in the question. Let the entity have a field of type `java.util.Date` where I want to save the point of time when the entity has been created. Now I want to ensure, that this values can not be changed (by accident) afterwards, so I would like to mark this field as `updatable=false`. But this leads to the problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use hibernate to do exactly what you are describing and I only get an insert statement.

I have something like this on my entity:

```
@PrePersist
private void onCreate() {
    persistDate = new Date();
}
```

The only time I would expect an insert followed by an update when persisting an entity would be if I was using @PostPersist.

The only thing I can think of why this isn't working in eclipselink correctly for you is eclipselink weaving settings are configured in an unexpected way. [See this documentation for more details.](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm)

One additional way to prevent changes to certain fields is by making the setter on the entity private. Hibernate and EclipseLink will be able to set the fields using reflection but it will prevent the developer from updating those fields.